Does an immortal Saiyan still get Zenkai Boosts?
Zenkai as an ability is a genetic trait that allows a Saiyan's power to increase substantially after recovering from near fatal injuries.
But, if a saiyan is immortal, if they get beaten up so bad, do they still get the boost?
